# Meaning of "danach" in the following context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adverb

Here is a sentence:

> Es gibt aber Sachen, die man vorher noch unbedingt erleben möchte und
> danach fragen wir jetzt die Menschen.

My question is what does "danach" mean in this context? What sentence member is it? I'm aware that it is basically a conjunctional adverb, but its direct English equivalents all sound awkward here.

Comment: What is your take on a translation? (It's the equivalent of "for" or "about" in "ask for" or "ask about".)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your confusion stems from the opposition of *vorher* and *danach*. This is a trick question.

That *danach* is not in opposition to *vorher* in this example. Rather than that, it's the *da*-Adverb of the preposition *nach*, which is required by the phrasal verb *fragen nach*.

> Wir fragen die Leute nach ihren Wünschen.

> Wir fragen die Leute danach.

So the English equivalent is the phrasal verb *to ask about* and *danach* is the same as *about that*.